# Open part of a PDF in HTML

Tags: html, pdf, embed

The size of my PDF is about 200 pages and i need to display on my web site only 10 pages of it.
**There is a way to display only the 10 pages without displaying the 200 others and wihtout changing my PDF size?**

I am working on IE8 and I did not find options of the `<embed>` tag to handle my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use server side logic and tools like TCPDF for PHP to extract this 10 pages from your PDF and show it in your browser in some way (as embed or converted into html) but there is no way to do that just with an  tag.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for this quick answer.